# Unchecking a Checkbox will uncheck other checkboxes in a table

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, html-table

I am using basic HTML `table`'s and `input` checkbox fields here.

This is what I want to accomplish with Javascript:

The second column of a table has one checkbox.  The third column contains "sub options" of the second column.  Each row is independent.

If I unselect a checkbox in the `<td>`, 2nd column, I want to deselect all of the check boxes in the `<td>` directly to the right (the sub options in the 3rd column).

I also want to do the opposite; if you select the first checkbox, it will check all of the ones in the sub options that are not checked.

Pseudo-Code ideas:

```
if checkbox checked:
  uncheck child input's in td `id`
```

OR

```
if checkbox checked:
   uncheck <check box one `id'>
   uncheck <check box two `id'>
   uncheck <check box three `id'>
   etc
```

The second option seems much more tedious.  Will the first work?

Comment: I want to answer, but I don't want to give out coding :\

Comment: I have not tried; I am not asking for code either.  I want to know, in general, what is the concept behind this?  My first guess is that I may need to have matching ID's or Classes, and just hard code the selected checkboxes that are related to each other?  Is there a simpler way where I can say, "uncheck all checkboxes that are a child of the `<td>`"?

Comment: Please put at least the HTML with the Table and CheckBoxes well formatted and will make easier to answer how to code the JavaScript for it.

Comment: I have added some psudo with the two options that I think may work; any feedback on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pure Javascript solution (no framework is tagged).

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5aEpB/)

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytable");
var checkbox;

for(var i=0; i<table.rows.length; i++){
    checkbox = table.rows[i].cells[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    checkbox.onchange = function(){
        var others = this.parentNode.parentNode.cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input");
        for(var j=0; j<others.length; j++){
            others[j].checked = this.checked;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's the definition of "nifty".

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

jQuery

```
$('#checkall:checkbox').change(function () {
if($(this).attr("checked")) $('input:checkbox').attr('checked','checked');
else $('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Agony/Dqnk5/3/)

Comment: That is very close to what I was asking for.  Now, every row on this table would have the same situation.  It seems I just need to add specific classes or ID's so that  one checkbox doesn't affect anything on another row.

Comment: Ah. So you have, say, 5 checkboxes, and you want the fourth one to check the last four, but not the first one?

Comment: Sort of.  Let's say this table has 5 rows, 3 columns.  Column 2 all the way down has 1 "master" checkbox.  Column 3 has 4 "sub option" checkboxes that are related to the "master" checkbox but only *on that same row*.  If you select the master checkbox, it will either uncheck (or check) ALL of the "sub option" checkboxes, again, *on that same row only*.

Comment: ok, the other guy pretty much answered it, wow.  Thanks though!

Comment: Haha thanks. I must admit, I like MrCode's answer better though. I wasn't even aware of how to do it in JS before now.